# Java 6 / Swing: Paint on top of JScrollPane's ViewPort / ViewPort-component

Tags: java, swing, rendering, jscrollpane, paint

I would like to implement a custom JScrollPane which is able to paint in it's client area **on top** of it's own ViewPort / ViewPort-component. The challenge with this is keep the custom paint-code repainting when the user scrolls the ViewPort or in other words, the ViewPort-component gets repainted.

My goal is to have the same effect as the semi-transparent scrollbars of iOS (iPhone/iPad), which are rendered on top of a scrollable list (instead of the classic scrollbars).

So this is just a painting question, not a question about scrolling :)

I already got something to work, which looks like this (the code below renders just a green test line above the JScrollPane):

```
public class ScrollPaneTest
{
    private JFrame          frame;
    private TestScrollPane  scrollPane;
    private JTextArea       textArea;

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel( "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel" );
        new ScrollpaneTest();
    }

    public ScrollPaneTest()
    {
        configureUi();

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                frame.setVisible( true );
            }
        } );
    }

    private void configureUi()
    {
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord( true );
        textArea.setLineWrap( true );
        textArea.setOpaque( false );
        textArea.setText( "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor "
                + "invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo "
                + "duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor "
                + "sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor "
                + "invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et "
                + "justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum "
                + "dolor sit amet." );

        scrollPane = new TestScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setViewportView( textArea );
        scrollPane.setLocation( 50, 50 );
        scrollPane.setSize( 200, 200 );

        frame = new JFrame( getClass().getSimpleName() );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setLayout( null );
        frame.setSize( 340, 380 );
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );

        frame.add( scrollPane );
    }
}

public class TestScrollPane extends JScrollPane
{
    public TestScrollPane()
    {
        setOpaque( true );
        setBackground( Color.WHITE );
    }

    @Override
    protected JViewport createViewport()
    {
        JViewport viewPort = super.createViewport();
        viewPort.setOpaque( false );

        return viewPort;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintChildren( Graphics g )
    {
        super.paintChildren( g );

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.setColor( Color.GREEN );
        g2d.drawLine( 0, 0, 100, 100 );
    }

}
```

Running the code, it looks like this:

[image]

The key here is to set the ViewPort and the ViewPort-component to non-opaque:

```
// From: ScrollPaneTest.configureUi()
textArea.setOpaque( false );
```

and:

```
// From: TestScrollPane.paintChildren()
JViewport viewPort = super.createViewport();
viewPort.setOpaque( false );
```

(*Without setting these to non-opaque, the JScrollPane would not be repainted, and the ViewPort-component (the JTextArea) would overpaint the green line*).

**Now my rather simple question is**:

Is there a better way to do it? Having to use `setOpaque( false)` on both components just doesn't feel right.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Well, instead of trying to paint directly onto the JScrollPane, you could take control of the layout management and layout out the view port and the scroll bars the way you want to. The difficulty here is telling with the corner and the row/column headers

Comment: @MadProgrammer interesting thought.. If I understand you correctly, I could try to layout the normal vertical JScrollBar so that it appears on top of the JScrollPane and then implement a custom painting for the JScrollBar? I'm not sure if the base code is capable of painting each one on top of the other without painting issues I avoid with my original approach. Because the main problem here is Java's painting optimization, hence those `setOpaque( false )`.

Comment: The `JViewport` and `JScrollbar` are components, so basically, yes, take control of the layout management (which is controlled by the `JScrollPane`).  You could make the `JScrollBar`s transparent for your needs, the trick then is to get them to "hide" after a period or show when moused over...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Having to use setOpaque( false) on both components just doesn't feel right.

Well, maybe a little easier. You can override the paintComponent() method of the JViewport then you only have to use setOpaque(false) on the text area, not the viewport :)

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ScrollPaneTest5
{
    private JFrame          frame;
    private JScrollPane  scrollPane;
    private JTextArea       textArea;

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel( "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel" );
        new ScrollPaneTest5();
    }

    public ScrollPaneTest5()
    {
        configureUi();

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                frame.setVisible( true );
            }
        } );
    }

    private void configureUi()
    {
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord( true );
        textArea.setLineWrap( true );
//        textArea.setOpaque( false );
        textArea.setText( "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor "
                + "invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo "
                + "duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor "
                + "sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor "
                + "invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et "
                + "justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum "
                + "dolor sit amet." );

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
//        scrollPane.setViewportView( textArea );
        scrollPane.setLocation( 50, 50 );
        scrollPane.setSize( 200, 200 );

        frame = new JFrame( getClass().getSimpleName() );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setLayout( null );
        frame.setSize( 340, 380 );
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );

        frame.add( scrollPane );



        JViewport viewport = new JViewport()
        {
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {
                super.paintComponent(g);

                g.setColor( Color.BLUE );
                g.drawArc( 100, 100, 80, 80, 0, 360);
            }
        };

        textArea.setOpaque( false );
        viewport.setView(textArea);
        scrollPane.setViewport( viewport );
    }
}
```

Otherwise, I would think you need to use the `JLayer` class. See the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Decorate Components with the JLayer Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html) for examples.

Comment: Interesting approach to simplify it - but unfortunateley, your example is not 100% correct. Try running it and then selecting the text in the JTextArea. You will see that the selection over-paints your circle. Going with my code (`setOpaque(false)`), the circle (or the green line) correctly paints over all - the JTextArea and it's selected text. But thanks for the hint with the JLayer - this is definitively the correct way to do it, I think.

Comment: @It'sLeto, `the selection over-paints your circle` - interesting, you learn something new every day :) However, it does seems to work in you override `paint()` instead of paintCompoennt(). However, I also agree that the JLayout is probably the better approach.

Comment: Ok, I think using JLayer is the correct answer for my question. I don't want to set your answer as correct, since the JLayer hint is just a bottom note :) What is a good way for Stackoverflow, do you want to give a separate answer (JLayer) which I can set as correct? Or should I set this answer as correct? Thanks :)

Comment: @It'sLeto, `I don't want to set your answer as correct, since the JLayer hint is just a bottom note :)` - the answer pointed you in the right direction and gave two possible solutions. In your comment you included the solution that you liked best. Others reading the post can choose which approach they like. So yes the question has been answered, since either approach works.

Comment: ok, I accepted your answer as the correct one - thanks a lot!